# assign free space Gparted - can not unmounted - /dev/nvme0n1p5

Tags: 20.04, gparted, resize, unmount

Apologized if this is a silly question however I am fairly new with Ubuntu.
I cannot assign free space to Ubuntu. What am I missing?

I am trying to increase the size of the space I have in Ubuntu (20.04). To do this I reduced my Windows 10 size. I see the space `unallocate`/available  in the `gparted` screen (details are in the pic below). However, I am not able to assign this available space to Ubuntu (`ext4/`). For instance, I tried unmouted my `ext4/` and for some reason it is not working.

[image]

I did some research [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I realized my partition name is different (`/dev/nvme0n1p5`) from what I found in the web (`/dev/sda`). Wonder if this is the reason why I cannot do it.
I am doing this **using my USB disk**.

Can you point me in the right direction to solve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't allocate free space to your ext4 partition because there is your swap between free space and ext4.

Try:

- Right click on your swap partition and select Resize/Move
- Drag and move the partition to the left, `Free space preceding` must be zero and `Free space following` must be 45.19GB.
- Now, unallocated space and ext4 are next to each other.
- Right click the ext4 partition and try to resize it.

If you can't move the swap partition, maybe it is used by the OS. Check with `swapon -s` if /dev/nvme0n1p4 is listed.
In this case, you can disable it with `swapoff`, then retry to move swap partition.

And if I'm not mistaken, /dev/nvme is used for nvme SSD on PCI-express slot, and /dev/sda is used of SATA drive.